# Google BigQuery - Duplicate imports with single Job

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there any known issue with BigQuery where single job results in duplicate import? We are seeing this issue and will need help to figure out the problem happening in BigQuery.

Our process runs every 15 min to import CSV to BigQuery. I have investigated looking into our logs and the job that was processed twice shows following issue. The CSV file that was processed twice has 36101 rows in it.

1. Our upload process successfully posted single Job to BigQuery. The CSV file posted for upload has 36101 rows and the size is 2846673
2. Our process checks for the status of the job. When checking for job status note the "outputRows". Same as expected (36101).

   "status": {
      "state": "RUNNING"
   },
   "statistics": {
      "startTime": "1356528625599",
      "load": {
         "inputFiles": "1",
         "inputFileBytes": "2846673",
         "outputRows": "36101",
         "outputBytes": "13651590"
      }
    }
    }
3. Note that after above job is completed the process shows double the record. See outputRows (72202)

   "status": {
      "state": "DONE"
    },
    "statistics": {
       "startTime": "1356528625599",
       "endTime": "1356528665201",
       "load": {
          "inputFiles": "1",
          "inputFileBytes": "2846673",
          "outputRows": "72202",
          "outputBytes": "27303180"
       }
     }
     }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've identified and fixed the bug. Please let us know if you hit any further problems.

Comment: I am not 100% sure if I have seen this before as we enabled our logging recently. I will look more and see if I can find any other instance of the job having same issue. Can you provide estimate on when this will be rolled out?

Comment: The fix is now in production. The answer above has been updated to indicate this.

Comment: Jordan, can you provide any more details on the fix? Under what scenarios was the bug happening? When did it start? When was it fixed? I experienced similar duplication issues.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, we've seen the same issue twice in the last five days. We are loading every 10 minutes, and just changed it to every hour to make this issue more manageable.